# What files does Coveralls select?

Tags: python, travis-ci, coveralls

I'm running Travis and Coveralls to run integration tests. It appears Coveralls is giving me a much higher rating than it should; I have only written tests for a handful of source files in my repository, and those are the only files that get checked for coverage (hence I get 95% coverage..). It appears as if files that do not have any tests specified do not get checked.

How does Coveralls select which files to check?

Perhaps my repository is a bit unusual, in that it contains several Python scripts that each have their own entry point. I am currently only testing one entry point, leaving the rest of the code completely untouched (and not even imported).

My `travis.yml` file simply executes `nose2`, which runs tests for this one entry point.

Comment: I think you'll only get coverage for files your tests touch at all, but you could try importing other entry points to find out.

Comment: I'm having that problem too :P